# perl: Why does shifting an array off an array of arrays add an extra level of indirection?

Tags: arrays, perl

The first line of my CSV file contains names for the fields below.
I read the file into an array of arrays, and try to shift off the 0th row.

But the array appears to be wrapped in another array level.

How can I get rid of that extra level of indirection?

Here's the code:

```
open CSV, "ExDivExport.csv" or die;;
@fields=();
while (<CSV>) 
{   chomp;
    ($temp) = /^"(.+)"$/; # remove first and last "
    @line=split /","/, $temp ;
    print"\n@line";  # all the lines print correctly here
    push @fields, [@line];
}
@names = shift @fields;   # Here I shift off the 0th row

print "\nat12 names=@names";         # prints: ARRAY(0x26e52c)
print "\nat13 names[0]=$names[0]";   # prints ARRAY(0x26e52c)
print "\nat14 names[0][0]=$names[0][0]"; # correctly prints first name 'Symbol'
```

Comment: If you get rid of that extra level of indirection, then you would have one array with all of the values from all rows of your csv file.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: Either way, you should not parse csv by yourself, you should use a library, otherwise you may get bitten by edge cases.  `Text::CSV` would be a good choice: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm

Comment: The extra level is coming because you are pushing `[ @line ]` onto your `@fields` array.  The `[ ... ]` wraps the contents in an Array Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code stored a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) to an array into `@fields` variable, so it's necessary to change the way you try to extract this kind of data:

```
$names = shift @fields;               # get a reference, so use $ sigil (scalar)
print "\nat12 names=@$names";         # dereference array ref
print "\nat13 names[0]=$names->[0]";  # get the first element (access with -> notation)
```

I think you are trying that for learning purposes. Other way, if you are serious about parsing CSV, it's better to use a well tested and documented module from CPAN, like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

Also, for debugging purposes, if you want to analyze the structure of a variable, [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) may helps you to understand it. For example:

```
print Dumper(\@names), "\n";
```

And your code opens the file in an old-way. There is a modern approach which uses a 3 params:

```
open CSV, "ExDivExport.csv" or die;;
```

should be

```
open my $CSV, '<', 'ExDivExport.csv' or die "cannot open file: $!";
#... then use the lexical variable $CSV instead of the CSV bareword
```

and don't forget to `close $CSV;`

Comment: When I say $names = shift @fields; , I just keep getting a reference to the SAME array, so all the members end up pointing to the Last array. I need to pass a deep copy.

Comment: @user1067305: Then there is more to your program than you have shown, and you must ask another question.

Comment: @user1067305 Why do you need deep copy ? "shift" will remove old array from outher array and it be lost.

Comment: Re "*and don't forget to `close $CSV;`*", Why? Adding that is useless without `use autodie;`.

Comment: @ikegami: Just for my own edification, can you explain why that is? Isn't it a good practice to close your file handles when you're done with them, autodie or not?

Comment: @mwp, Yes, but that would happen anyway as the scalar goes out of scope. Calling `close` without checking for an error is therefore redundant.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, that makes sense. I didn't see the scalar going out of scope in any of the snippets here so I thought maybe I was missing something. Thank you for taking a moment to answer my question!

Comment: @mwp, They go out of scope when at end of file. If they don't go out of scope, I'd rather create a scope than add `close` since there's no reason to keep a closed file handle around!

Answer (score 0):

So, all I had to do was replace:

@names = shift @fields;

with

@names = @{shift @fields};

Problem solved.

Comment: As you found out the "level of indirection" was not *added* by `shift`. It is *there for every row*, but you wanted to have it removed to extract the list of names.

Comment: That's an aweful solution. It needlessly makes a copy of the array. As previously mentioned, you should be using `my $names = shift @fields;`